# Creating a new object of the same class as a given object

Tags: dart

So I have something like the following:

```
abstract class Animal { }

class Dog extends Animal { }

class Cat extends Animal { }
```

I want to make a function `makeABaby(Animal parent)` which will call either the `Cat()` or `Dog()` constructor depending on which type was actually passed into the function, and return the new object.

I could do something like `if(parent is Cat) { return Cat(); }` etc. in the function, but that's hard to maintain as the number of animal species grows, so I'm looking for something a bit more dynamic. Ideally I'd like to do something like

```
Animal makeABaby(Animal parent) {
  return parent.getConstructor().apply();
}
```

but I'm not sure how I can make that work in Dart, or if it's something that can be done without having to resort to reflection. Is there anything in the language that I can leverage for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection in a package `dart:mirrors`.

```dart
import 'dart:mirrors';

abstract class Animal {
  static Animal makeABaby(Animal parent) {
    ClassMirror cm = reflectClass(parent.runtimeType);
    InstanceMirror im = cm.newInstance(const Symbol(''), []);

    var baby = im.reflectee;

    return baby;
  }
}

class Dog extends Animal {}
class Cat extends Animal {}

void main() {
  var a = Dog();
  var b = Cat();

  print(Animal.makeABaby(a));
  print(Animal.makeABaby(b));
}
```

Output:

```
Instance of 'Dog'
Instance of 'Cat'
```